# How to get event to stack in php calendar

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

I have a PHP calendar class that displays a calendar for a webpage, currently working but when more than one event is added to the same day. Only the firstly created event shows. Ive been debugging for a while and cannot figure out why. If anyone has any guidance let me know:

Calendar Class:

```
<?php

    class Calendar {
        private $active_year, $active_month, $active_day;
        private $events = [];
    
        public function __construct($date = null) {
            $this->active_year = $date != null ? date('Y', strtotime($date)) : date('Y');
            $this->active_month = $date != null ? date('m', strtotime($date)) : date('m');
            $this->active_day = $date != null ? date('d', strtotime($date)) : date('d');
        }
    
        public function add_event($txt, $date, $days = 1, $color = '') {
            $color = $color ? ' ' . $color : $color;
            $this->events[] = [$txt, $date, $days, $color];
        }
    
        public function __toString() {
            $num_days = date('t', strtotime($this->active_day . '-' . $this->active_month . '-' . $this->active_year));
            $num_days_last_month = date('j', strtotime('last day of previous month', strtotime($this->active_day . '-' . $this->active_month . '-' . $this->active_year)));
            $days = [0 => 'Sun', 1 => 'Mon', 2 => 'Tue', 3 => 'Wed', 4 => 'Thu', 5 => 'Fri', 6 => 'Sat'];
            $first_day_of_week = array_search(date('D', strtotime($this->active_year . '-' . $this->active_month . '-1')), $days);
            $html = '<div class="calendar">';
            $html .= '<div class="header">';
            $html .= '<div class="month-year">';
            $html .= date('F Y', strtotime($this->active_year . '-' . $this->active_month . '-' . $this->active_day));
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="days">';
            foreach ($days as $day) {
                $html .= '
                    <div class="day_name">
                        ' . $day . '
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            for ($i = $first_day_of_week; $i > 0; $i--) {
                $html .= '
                    <div class="day_num ignore">
                        ' . ($num_days_last_month-$i+1) . '
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_days; $i++) {
                $selected = '';
                if ($i == $this->active_day) {
                    $selected = ' selected';
                }
                $html .= '<div class="day_num' . $selected . '">';
                $html .= '<span>' . $i . '</span>';
                foreach ($this->events as $event) {
                    for ($d = 0; $d <= ($event[2]-1); $d++) {
                        if (date('y-m-d', strtotime($this->active_year . '-' . $this->active_month . '-' . $i . ' -' . $d . ' day')) == date('y-m-d', strtotime($event[1]))) {
                            $html .= '<div class="event' . $event[3] . '">';
                            $html .= $event[0];
                            $html .= '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $html .= '</div>';
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= (42-$num_days-max($first_day_of_week, 0)); $i++) {
                $html .= '
                    <div class="day_num ignore">
                        ' . $i . '
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            return $html;
        }
    
    }

?>
```

and here is the Calendar.css:

```
.calendar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.calendar .header .month-year {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #636e73;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.header{
    height: 10%;
}
.calendar .days {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.calendar .days .day_name {
    width: calc(87.5% / 7);
    height: 5%;
    border-right: 1px solid #2c7aca;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #818589;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #448cd6;
}
.calendar .days .day_name:nth-child(7) {
    border: none;
}
.calendar .days .day_num {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: calc(76.75% / 7);
    width: calc(87.5% / 7);
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e9ea;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e9ea; */
    /* padding: 10px; */
    /* padding: 1%; */
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #7c878d;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* min-height: 100px; */
    min-height: 20%;
    /* min-height: 5%; */
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}
.calendar .days .day_num span {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 30px;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: small;
}
.calendar .days .day_num .event {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 200%;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f7c30d;
    color: #fff;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.calendar .days .day_num .event.green {
    background-color: #51ce57;
}
.calendar .days .day_num .event.blue {
    background-color: #518fce;
}
.calendar .days .day_num .event.red {
    background-color: #ce5151;
}
.calendar .days .day_num:nth-child(7n+1) {
    border-left: 1px solid #e6e9ea;
}
.calendar .days .day_num:hover {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
.calendar .days .day_num.ignore {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-color: black;
    color: #ced2d4;
    cursor: inherit;
}
.calendar .days .day_num.selected {
    background-color: #f1f2f3;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use an established calendar library such as https://fullcalendar.io or something similar?

Comment: I've used this same php calendar (from CodeShack.io I believe) successfully with multiple events per day; add to the post the rendered html for a day where you think you've added multiple events; add the php code which adds the events as well.

Comment: Unable to replicate stated problem. Adding multiple events for the same day appears to work OK